# Как выбрать диапазон дат?

Tags: sqlite, запрос

Как можно сделать запрос в SQLite по датам например 2012-09-01 по 2012-09-29. Тип данных  `Datetime`, а сама дата хранится в виде строки.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html

Answer (score 0):

Ответ тривиальный до ужаса:

```
select * from data where Time>= '2012-09-01' AND time < '2012-09-29'
```

Comment: строка же... не пойдет.. надо юзать функции из документации, я как о делал, там можно указать маску даты и тогда уже брать дмапазон правильный

Comment: а ссылку в меня , где почитать можно если не сложно.